# Redux async actions getState() returning undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm stuck with a problem I encountered with redux-thunk, I'm trying to get the properties of my redux state so as to dispatch relevant actions, when I call the getState() the first time, I get the values but subsequent calls to getState() returns undefined, I noticed when i checked the state, the subscriptions array was empty after the first call, i'm not sure why this is happening. Below is a snippet of my code... Thanks in advance guys.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns
>   that element. This method changes the length of the array.

So you're actually changing your state when doing `getState().user.subscriptions.pop()`

If you want the last item of the array (without removing) do this:

```
const subscriptions = getState().user.subscriptions;
let currentPlan = subscriptions[subscriptions.length - 1];
```

Comment: Yes... I just realized it just now. Thanks. @muZk